# Search for a file name or DLL in VS 2015 - Source Control Explorer

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

[image]I am looking for an option like  'wildcard' search in VS 2015 - Source control explorer. But not seeing any search option to search for a file or DLL [It shows option to search Changest, label].

Answer (score 6):

In Source Control right click on your project and go to `find>find by wildcard`. To get this functionality [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) Need to be installed, after installation close and reopen VS.

[image: Source Control Find]

Also you can query Work Items in TFS like so. In VS go to the `Team` drop down and select `New Query`. This will allow you to search TFS work items.

[image: TFS New Query]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't see 'Find By Wildcard' option [Please see the screenshot in my question - I have added now]. Do you know should I enable some setting? Thanks!

Comment: yes you need TFS Power Tools installed. I updated my answer with a link.